# Our project makes constant use of static outer classes that have non-static nested classes - might this have any pitfalls?

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

We're currently working on a Web-API project written in C#. It contains a lot of static outer classes that have non-static nested classes. Something like

```
public static class OuterClass
{    
    public class InnerClass : ParentClass
    {
            
    }
}
```

This pattern is used regularly throughout the project, hence my question. Are there any pitfalls in using a static outer class that has a non-static nested class? Let alone, using a lot of them throughtout the application?

Comment: Does the static class have any other thing apart from inner classes?

Comment: I think  this is an example of "static classes as namespaces" anti-pattern

Comment: The static outer class has no members. It has just _public_ inner classes. But these have  members (that is, fields, properties, methods, and so on).

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd say *why* you are doing this strange thing. It's not necessarily wrong but it is sufficiently odd that I'd want a solid justification if asked to review this code.

Comment: @EricLippert, I am not the author of the code so I cannot do justice to the explanation why that choice was made. But, after having spoken with the author, I understand the following. The outer static class is a way to implement an API resource in a [Vertical Slice Architecture](https://jimmybogard.com/vertical-slice-architecture/).The request's Query, Validator, Result, Handler, and so on, are each implemented using a public non-static inner class.

Comment: Have you learned anything from the previous instance of the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65519928/static-outer-class-having-inner-class-what-are-the-advantages-and-pitfalls

Comment: Thanks for that sketch; that's helpful. The question I would ask when critiquing this design choice is: what compelling benefit over namespaces does this static class approach yield? I don't see any harm offhand but if there is no benefit over doing it using namespaces as they were designed, then I would typically follow the standard design pattern. One typically only uses static classes for storing globally useful methods, and particularly extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

- If there are only inner classes, but not also fields and methods, then namespaces may be preferred instead of those outer public static classes.

  - You can define fields and methods in a static class (or class in general) but not a namespace
  - The `using` keyword is a convenient way to import all of the accessible types/classes defined in a namespace, so that you do not need to fully qualify them.
  - Otherwise, if you intend to add members/methods, then it makes sense to keep those as classes.
- Especially if the project will be used as a library, you should still use namespaces to avoid collisions in the global namespace.

Comment: Regarding the `using` keyword: For static classes, you can use the [using static directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static).